# matplotlib + latex: kpsewhich pop up - mathtext.fontset is being ignored

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am struggling with the following problem. When I plot a figure using matplotlib in combination with Latex I get multiple successive pop-ups of kpsewhich (some file from Miktex) when executing the python file containing the figure (about 10 pop-ups). This is annoying, but the real problem is that in addition some commands from my matplotlib RcParameter file are ignored, including mathtex.fontset (which I try to set to sans-serif).

All of this started to happen sometime when I updated to Spyder 3 and Matplotlib 2.0, it seems to be an interplay of my Latex and my Matplotlib, but I cannot figure out what's happening.

**My system:** I am running Windows 10 64 bit, originally with Python-xy, Latex 2.7.10 (32 bit), Spyder 3, Matplotlib 2, Ghostscript 9.21 (32 bit) and Miktex 2.9.6361 (32 bit)

A colleague of mine ran into the same issue after updating his Python-xy installation to the newest Matplotlib 2.

I know my explanation is a bit vague at this point in time but I am struggling to narrow the problem down. I attached a picture of the [kpsewhich pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcYfF.png) and my problem with the ignored [sans-serif mathtext.fontset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3xDp.png).

If you have any hint on what could cause such a behavior or if you experienced a similar behavior, your support would be very much appreciated.

Thank you, L.

Comment: I believe adding some of your code would help.

Comment: There are two different problems here and I would strongly suggest to keep them separate. One being the popups, the other being the fonts. There is no reason to believe that they are related in any way. So I guess you may edit this question to ask about one of the two problems and ask a new question about the other. In each case try to be as specific as possible and include relevant code (which I suppose can be really short, but also different in both cases).

Comment: I combined the two problems since they appeared together. My code worked fine before the updates, and so did my colleague's code. This lead me to the conclusion that we have a compatibility problem, but I am struggling to see where.

Comment: Well, it may be that both problems are caused by an update, which doesn't mean they have anything to do with each other, as updates change a lot of different settings at once.